# Subclassing view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to subclass UIViewController and override init methods. I ended up with:

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController, BaseViewCreating, ModelBinding {

    var viewModel : Any!

    convenience init(viewModel: Any){
        self.init()
        self.createUserInterface()
        self.createConstraints()
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.bindWithModel(model: self.viewModel)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init()
        self.createUserInterface()
        self.createConstraints()
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func createUserInterface() {

    }

    func createConstraints() {


    }

    func bindWithModel(model: Any) {


    }

    func update(){
        self.bindWithModel(model: self.viewModel)
    }
}
```

However, when app launch, it throw an error - EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line `self.init()` in method `convenience init()`.
How to fix that?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, not with a `convenience init`.

Comment: I would recommend to use the `–viewDidLoad` method instead of the `–init`, that seems a more standard way of dealing with view-lifecycle properly; your way is kinda unconventional in case if view-controllers.

Comment: Oh, true. Missed that.

Comment: You shouldn't create a convenience initializer method with the same function signature as the default initializer, since the compiler most probably won't be able to decide which one you wanted to call. Moreover, you're not overriding anything, you're just creating extra convenience initializers.

Comment: Not related but rather than most unspecified `Any` use a protocol as parameter type which all dedicated models could conform to. And if the model is supposed to be optional use a regular optional (`?`).

Comment: why don't you override viewDidLoad and customize it there?

Comment: @holex how to pass view model to view controller then?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban, you don't need to pass, the _model_ is supposed to be available globally in your app; but in some cases you need creating a property in your new class and populate the value in the `–performSegue:...` method or if you are an old fashioned one, you can use the same method which invokes the `–pushViewController:...` method – but it highly depends on the actual view-hierarchy you are dealing with; but don't try thinking in _view-models_ and _view-controllers_, try to convert your brain to build up a pure MVC architecture instead, that is the best way in long term.

Comment: @holex i dont mean model like data base model, i mean model for view controller (i preffer MVVM pattern). So, i need to pass it somehow to my view controller with initialization.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban, I suspected to prefer MVVM, that is why I said that you are supposed to forget about MVVM, and start thinking in MVC – because entire Apple SDK expects you to use the frameworks, delegates, protocols, etc... (literally everything) in pure MVC environment, so your preference of MVVM may give you hard times here; but back the original question: a few common options for passing data over is already in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you are calling `init` `recursively` with `self.init` inside

```
convenience init() {
   self.init()
}
```

Every single Convenience init should call designated initializer of the class. UIViewController has

```
public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)

public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

as designated initializer. So you should call any one of them in your init() or override them in your ViewController and later call `self.init(nibName` or `self.init(coder`

As it cant find designated initializer by name init() it is calling recursively your init hence crashing

**EDIT:**

Just in case anybody has a doubt that self.init will not result in loop because thats one of the way how a Convenience initializer can call designated initializer. I have explained in detail why it results in infinite loop in this specific case in comment below :) attaching a proof here

[image]

This is the stack trace when I ran OP code. Clearly shows infinite recursive call

Comment: @dávid-pásztor UIViewController does not have any designated initializer by signature init()

Comment: @dávid-pásztor : With all due respect I know you can call self.init method but thats not the only way how initializers have to be defined. If your class in not inheriting from any other class and if you happened to have a designated / required initializer and a convenience initializer as well then your convenience initializer can call designated initializers by calling self.designatedInit but if you are inheriting from a existing class which has its own designated initializer declared already you can always say super.designatedInit unless you override them and provided custom implementation

Comment: @dávid-pásztor : In this case however class is being inherited from UIViewController which has its designated initailizer declared. All subclasses inherits the parents designated and required initializers. But because there is no initializer by name init in UIViewController and OP has declared his own convenience initializer of name init() when u call self.init it cant find such method in parent hence loops back and results in recursive call. lemme know if I missed something :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone face same problem i paste answer here:

You should add this to your subclas:

```
  init() {
        super.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
        self.createUserInterface()
        self.createConstraints()
    }
```